# New dac does not appear in type relation

Tags: acumatica

I Add the Attestation DAC, I would like add this type in the Relation entity.

**update**

```
namespace ATTESTATION
{
  [Serializable]
  [PXCacheName("ATTESTATION")]
  [PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(ATTESTATIONGR))]
  public class ATTESTATION : IBqlTable
  {
    #region Id
    [PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)]
    
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
    public abstract class id : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<id> { }
    #endregion

    #region Atnum
    [PXDBString(40, IsUnicode = true, IsKey=true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Num Attestation", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible,Required = true)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(ATTESTATION.atnum),typeof(ATTESTATION.atclt),DescriptionField=typeof(ATTESTATION.atnum),Filterable = true)]   
    //[PXFieldDescription]
    [PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]      
    public virtual string Atnum { get; set; }
    public abstract class atnum : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<atnum> { }
    #endregion    

    #region NoteID
    [PXNote( ShowInReferenceSelector = true,Selector = typeof(ATTESTATION.atnum),DescriptionField = typeof(ATTESTATION.atnum))]

    public virtual Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
    public abstract class noteID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<noteID> { }
    #endregion
```

1 / When, we are in the new screen, we can create a form

[image]

2 / We create a new activity

[image]

3 / But in the new task, we have the entity, but not the type.
So the type ATTESTATION does not appear on the lookup.
[image]

What should we do to have the list up to date?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? Maybe add a little more source code to see what's going on and where?

Comment: @ZoltanFebert , it's update :) Thanks !

Comment: Did my solution work?

Comment: @ZoltanFebert, excuse me for delay, I try your solution and another, but the new DAC not appear in the type of Relation. I don't know if it's possible to add new dac in this list ?

Comment: Yes, PXSearchable attribute on NoteID adds the new DAC to that list. I tried it before posting my answer. I don't know what you missed. If you can upload your customization package somewhere I can take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to PXSearchable attribute to your Note field.

```
#region NoteID
public abstract class noteID : BqlGuid.Field<noteID> { }
[PXSearchable(0, "{0}", new Type[] { typeof(ATTESTATION.atnum) },
    new Type[] { typeof(ATTESTATION.atnum) }
)]
[PXNote( ShowInReferenceSelector = true,Selector = typeof(ATTESTATION.atnum),DescriptionField = typeof(ATTESTATION.atnum))]
public virtual Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
#endregion
```

Please check Acumatica source code for more detailed examples, you can find some on POOrder or SOOrder NoteID fields.
Probably you need to implement a few more parameters, with this basic config your DAC will show up in the Entity selector.

Comment: When I add PXSerchable, I have not the type "ATTESTATION" in the combobox TypeRelation (in Yellow on the picture)